# Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source' when running React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just created a React App with `create-react-app aquastars` and then eject the dependencies using `yarn run eject` and when I run the app I get the following error.

> Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source'

I haven't done anything!  What do I need to do to get this up and running?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `npm install` ?

Comment: Thanks connexo I am running that now.

Comment: same issue, how did you solve it?

Comment: Let me know if my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258361/7869175) works for you. If so, would love for you to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 44):

The [solution by @xiaobo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53551989/7869175) was actually insufficient for me. It took me a while to figure this out after upgrading expo to v32, so here's what I did in case anyone else has the same problem. (Answer from [expo forums](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2574).)

If you have a `.babelrc` file in the root of your repository, re-name it to something like `.babelrc-old` so it doesn't get used.

**Add a file called `babel.config.js` to the root of your repository**.

**Put this in the babel.config.js file:**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

All set!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like a good first answer, but please edit your post to remove the reference to "the answer above" because the answer order can change.

Comment: Hey, got it, thanks so much for the tip! I just edited it to link to the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nando, you saved my day!

Comment: @Fl4v happy to hear it! :)

Comment: Just updated Expo SDK in my app from v32 to v35 and ran into this issue. This solution resolved the issue for me also. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it @JoshBuchea

Answer (score 27):

After you execute `npm run eject`:

1. `cd /your/project/path` (ignore)
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm install` or `yarn install`
4. Run the script, which was failing before (in your case most likely: `yarn start` or `npm start`).

Comment: Why not yarn in the 3rd step . I tried installing with yarn. It worked 

Comment: it is the same command https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/#toc-default-command

Answer (score 8):

Delete the whole `node_modules` and re-run `yarn` to make it work.

`rm -R node_modules/
rm yarn.lock
yarn install`

Comment: Deleting yarn.lock is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with @graup, there should be no need to deleted `yarn.lock` and it's the one thing that's gonna try and keep all your dependencies the same between machines/environments.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was solved by installing, on Reactjs, "@babel", `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`

1: `yarn add @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` 
2: `yarn start`

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source' with '@babel/transform-react-jsx-source'

Comment: replace it where? (nvm I found it.. .babelrc in root which is hidden file)

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 system this error was caused by switching to git-bash (as the default shell used by npm to run any scripts from package.json).
I had previously done `npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"` in another project to be able to run any scripts that contained bash syntax.
I could revert it via `npm config delete script-shell` and the error was gone.
[more](https://fmacedoo.medium.com/how-to-set-gitbash-as-the-default-npm-script-runner-on-windows-50d6bd670715)

Answer (score -1):

Vanished this error after just **changed the name of *“.babelrc”* file** which was at the **root of the repository**.