# Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

After `npm run eject` (this was needed in order to change the webpack.config), I've run into the following problem during the app compilation: `Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy'`.

I've tried multiple variants that are described here:
[Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source' when running React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327625/cannot-find-module-babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source-when-running-react)

(one of the most popular was to delete node modules and do `yarn install` again - it didn't help)

What could be done to fix that issue?

**Here is my `.babelrc` file:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-2",
    "react-app",
    "babel-preset-expo"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "istanbul"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**And my `package.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "maperclip-react",
  "version": "3.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://maperclip-server:3001",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.4.10",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.1.5",
    "@babel/core": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.0.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.0.2",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.2.0",
    "array-move": "^2.1.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-v4-rtl": "^4.3.1-3",
    "bpmn-js": "^4.0.4",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "can-use-dom": "^0.1.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "downshift": "^3.2.10",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.4",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "firebase": "^6.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.2.3",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.17.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.21.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.4.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.1",
    "react-ckeditor-component": "^1.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.17.3",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-d3-speedometer": "^0.5.5",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.6.2",
    "react-dnd": "^7.4.5",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^7.4.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.1.5",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.9.0",
    "react-joyride": "^2.0.5",
    "react-jvectormap": "^0.0.12",
    "react-load-script": "^0.0.6",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-number-format": "^4.0.8",
    "react-placeholder": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.4",
    "react-simple-maps": "^0.12.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.9.1",
    "react-star-rating-component": "^1.4.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "recharts": "^1.6.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "resolve": "1.12.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.4",
    "typeface-roboto": "^0.0.54",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "4.41.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "/Users/ivan/MyCubes/MaperClip_Athlon/Maperclip/client_react/src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've also done `yarn add babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` - it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `@babel v7` but `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` is a plugin for `babel 6`.

You should use `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`.

More info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

```
(...)
"plugins": [
  "syntax-dynamic-import",
  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
  "react-hot-loader/babel"
]
(...)
```

and

```
npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

Comment: I've installed the `@babel` plugins (I'm using yarn as a package manager) and now, I receive the following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' from '/app'`

Comment: Yes, use `@babel/preset-env`, `babel-preset-es2015` is deprecated

Comment: `react-app` (and `babel-preset-expo`) should be enough, though.